# What is the option to partition huge amount of data from a source using ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory, kql, azure-data-explorer

I have a pipeline on ADF with a `For Loop` activity and inside I have a `Data Flow` running a Kusto query. In this loop I am using a variable with 10 string in an array, so that my Data Flow will run based on those values as a parameter.

[image]

This is my dataflow and my partition method from the `Optimized` tab:

[image]

I am using a Kusto query as a source, but this query has a huge amount of data overall, but for each loop it has 100 million rows. If I partition my data like the image below would the source get results by each partition or get the whole output and then partition?

Ex: If I set my partition as a round robin option and with 200 partitions. Would the query works 200 times with 500k rows each time or run once with 100M rows and THEN partition later?

My problem is, if I use for example:

```
MyTable | take 100000
```

The pipeline will succeed just fine, but if I keep the original dataset from the source (100M rows each loop) it will eventually fail, and SOMETIMES only it will succeed.

The pipeline would succeed like I mention, which will be the same as running the Kusto query with the `hash` partition for example.